# Windows Error Reporting "AppHangTransient" Event

Tags: .net, freeze, windows-error-reporting

One of our clients has reported performance issues for our .NET application.

We've asked them to inspect their Windows event logs and have noticed that Windows Error Reporting has logged several Information level entries relating to the application.  What does "AppHangTransient" mean for WER?  The suggestion may be that the hang was transient, but I cannot find written confirmation.

> Fault bucket , type 0
>
> Event Name: AppHangTransient
>
> Response: Not available
>
> Cab Id: 0